# CSS3 writing-mode not working when exporting to image/pdf from webpage

Tags: css, phantomjs, html2canvas

I am using CSS3 property `writing-mode: tb-rl;` for rendering vertical text on top of a Map image. This is showing perfectly in the recent versions of Chrome, Firefox etc. However, chromeless libraries like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html) or the famous [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) are unable to render this in the output image. All the layout and everything else is fine in the png output, but this text becoming horizontal is ruining it. Is there a way to capture the page as it appears in the browser (just like a screenshot of a wrapper `div`) using Javascript ?

Comment: Try using Selenium with Chrome driver.

Comment: If PNG works, then use it. If you still want to use PDF, then find another way to change text direction and see if PhantomJS applies it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using CSS transform's `rotate` to make the text vertical, and then PhantomJS recognizes the vertical text. Seems like `writing-mode: tb-rl;` is too new to be rendered by most of these libraries which take the DOM and then export it into an image using Canvas.